# Docker / Azerothcore connection configuration, unable to connect

Tags: azerothcore

I can not connect to server running on Docker through WoWclient on same computer let alone on network.

Tried changing worldserver.conf inside C:\Users\Seth\azerothcore-wotlk\docker\worldserver\etc to

```
LoginDatabaseInfo     = "127.0.0.1;3306;root;password;acore_auth"
WorldDatabaseInfo     = "127.0.0.1;3306;root;password;acore_world"
CharacterDatabaseInfo = "127.0.0.1;3306;root;password;acore_characters"
```

I've also left it default.

I am able to connect through HeidiSQL with 127.0.0.1 3306 and am able to change realmlist to 127.0.0.1

When I type "docker ps" into gitBash

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
ba3bc132e076        azerothcore/worldserver   "/azeroth-server/bin…"   24 hours ago        Up 11 seconds       0.0.0.0:8085->8085/tcp              azerothcore-wotlk_ac-worldserver_1
6b4d4d41f814        azerothcore/authserver    "/azeroth-server/bin…"   24 hours ago        Up 11 seconds       0.0.0.0:3724->3724/tcp              azerothcore-wotlk_ac-authserver_1
8501ee8e2202        azerothcore/database      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 hours ago        Up 12 seconds       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   azerothcore-wotlk_ac-database_1
```

I don't know if I am not doing something right with docker or if its my WoW 3.3.5a client I downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was Client I downloaded automatically patched config.wtf file to connect to their server. Had to go inside WoTLK\Data\enGB and change realmlist inside there. Not sure if this is true for all clients.

Comment: yes, ALWAYS change the `realmlist.wtf` file that is inside `Data/enXX` (where `XX` depends on your client's language)

Answer (score 0):

The ip address must refer to your container database address, which is `ac-database` by default with the Docker setup. For example:

```
LoginDatabaseInfo = "ac-database;3306;root;password;acore_auth"
```

so you should NOT use `127.0.0.1` here.

Then you should set your realmlist as:

`set realmlist localhost`

Comment: Come to find out client I downloaded automatically updated config.wtf file so now I am able to connect using localhost. problem now is It sticks at "Logging into game server"

Comment: If you don't mind me asking what is the next step to connecting to a friend over the internet? I have azerothcore running on docker. I am able to log into game on a seperate pc on the network with 192.168.1.242 Docker gives me a 10.0.75.0 address that doesn't seem to do anything? I've tried port forwarding ports 3724 and 8085 on my router.